# Use SI units in sympy rather than Hartree units

Tags: python, sympy, physics

I am trying to use `sympy` to calculate wave functions for the hydrogen atom, and would like to use SI units rather than Hartree units. The documentation gives lots of examples, but all using Hartree units.
Is there a way of switching to SI units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search on the Internet, I found no definitive explanation on using `sympy` hydrogen atom code with SI units. I therefore conclude that the `sympy` calculations for the hydrogen atom have to be performed in Hartree units. Consequently, the outputs will also be in Hartree units and, if needed, have to be converted to SI units.

Some examples of how to get SI units from the `sympy` output in Hartree units are given below:

```
length, L: multiply by 0.529E-10 [m]  (Bohr radius, a0)
mass,   m: multiply by 9.109E-31 [kg] (rest mass of electron, me)      
energy, E: multiply by 27.211    [eV] (4.3597E-18 [J])
charge, C: multiply by 1.602E-19 [C]  (Coulomb)
```

With regard to the wave function, it is a derived unit and should be multiplied by the Bohr radius raised to the -3/2 power, i.e. a0^{-3/2}.

I hope some people will find this usefull.

Ref:   [Wikipedia]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units